# Using beep sound at point of error in python

Tags: python, error-handling, pycharm, beep

I want to add beep sound when an error occurs in python script. I know how to add windows beep after specific line e.g.

```
 duration = 1000  # milliseconds
    freq = 440  # Hz
     #some code here
    winsound.Beep(freq, duration)
```

Is it possible to enable beep whenever there is an error? I am using windows 10, python 3.6, and pycharm IDE. I couldn't find any feature in pycharm that gives audio notification on error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch all errors globally and beep when an error occurs:

```
try:
    do_something()
except:
    winsound.Beep(440, 1000)
```

Comment: It helps with beep sound at error but then I can't see error statement due to exception

Comment: Oh! Thanks for pointing it out. And then you can use a `raise` after the beep, so the error gets re-raised. @Iramshahzadi

Comment: Thanks David, this is what I wanted :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this one in Windows:

```
import winsound
try:
    int('abc')
except Exception as e:
    winsound.PlaySound("*", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
    raise e
```

Replace `int('abc')` with your code.

NOTE: It can be used only in "Windows". Not applicable to Linux / Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm-specific: By now, there is also an option to have a sound play at certain events, for example hitting a breakpoint ("Breakpoint hit"). ( [Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-notifications.html)/[archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20230327001630/https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-notifications.html), see "Play sound".)

Trying it quickly, I couldn't find the option to play a sound when an exception is hit (it is *not* the option "Error Report"). But enabling sound for "Breakpoint hit" for me does the job, together with enabling breakpoints when an untreated exception is hit.

According to the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-notifications.html), it works for Windows, Linux and MacOs.

[image]